# Upload de Imagens não funciona PHP

Tags: php, upload, image

Tenho a seguinte página em PHP:

```
<?php 
session_start();
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Cadastro de Operacional</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
    var max_fields      = 10; //maximum input boxes allowed
    var wrapper         = $(".input_fields_wrap"); //Fields wrapper
    var add_button      = $(".add_field_button"); //Add button ID

    var x = 1; //initlal text box count
    $(add_button).click(function(e){ //on add input button click
        e.preventDefault();
        if(x < max_fields){ //max input box allowed
            x++; //text box increment
            $(wrapper).append('<div><br>Posto '+x+'<p><input type="text" name="posto'+x+'" class="form-control"/></p><p><input type="file" name="arquivo'+x+'"></p><a href="#" class="remove_field btn btn-danger">Remover Posto</a></div>'); 
            window.scrollTo(0,document.querySelector(".scrollingContainer").scrollHeight);

//add input box
}
});

    $(wrapper).on("click",".remove_field", function(e){ //user click on remove text
        e.preventDefault(); $(this).parent('div').remove(); x--;

    })
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <?php
    if(!empty($_SESSION['cadastro'])){ 
        if($_SESSION['permite_cadastrar'] == 0){
            ?>
            <script language="JavaScript"> 
                window.location="inicial.php"; 
                window.alert("Acesso Negado! Sem permissão!");
            </script> 
            <?php
        }   
    }else{
        $_SESSION['msg'] = "Área restrita";
        ?> 
        <script language="JavaScript"> 
            window.location="index.php"; 
            window.alert("Area Restrita");
        </script> 

        <noscript> 
            Se não for direcionado automaticamente, clique <a href="index.php">aqui</a>. 
        </noscript>
    </script>
    <?php
}
include_once("navbar.php");
?>
<div class="container">
    <form class="form-horizontal" method="POST" action="cadastrar_operacional.php" name="form1">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-2">
                <br>Referência: <input type="text" name="referencia"  class="form-control">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <br>Posto 1:<input type="text" name="posto1" class="form-control"/>
                <input name="arquivo1" type="file"  />
                <div class="input_fields_wrap">

                    <div>

                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <br>

        <button class="add_field_button btn btn-info">Adicionar novo posto</button>
        <input type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-success" value="Cadastrar Referência">    
    </form>
</div>


</body>
</html>
```

E o form processa aqui:

```
<?php 
session_start();
include_once("conexao.php");
?>
<?php
/******
 * Upload de imagens
 ******/
 // verifica se foi enviado um arquivo
if ( isset( $_FILES[ 'arquivo1' ][ 'name' ] ) && $_FILES[ 'arquivo1' ][ 'error' ] == 0 ) {
   $arquivo_tmp = $_FILES[ 'arquivo1' ][ 'tmp_name' ];
   $nome = $_FILES[ 'arquivo1' ][ 'name' ];

    // Pega a extensão
   $extensao = pathinfo ( $nome, PATHINFO_EXTENSION );

    // Converte a extensão para minúsculo
   $extensao = strtolower ( $extensao );

    // Somente imagens, .jpg;.jpeg;.gif;.png
    // Aqui eu enfileiro as extensões permitidas e separo por ';'
    // Isso serve apenas para eu poder pesquisar dentro desta String
   if ( strstr ( '.jpg;.jpeg;.gif;.png', $extensao ) ) {
        // Cria um nome único para esta imagem
        // Evita que duplique as imagens no servidor.
        // Evita nomes com acentos, espaços e caracteres não alfanuméricos
    $novoNome = uniqid ( time () ) . '.' . $extensao;

        // Concatena a pasta com o nome
    $destino1 = 'imagens / ' . $novoNome;

        // tenta mover o arquivo para o destino
    if ( @move_uploaded_file ( $arquivo_tmp, $destino1 ) ) {
        echo ' <img src = "' . $destino1 . '" class="resize" >';

    }
    else
        echo 'Erro ao salvar o arquivo. Aparentemente você não tem permissão de escrita.<br />';
}
else
    echo 'Você poderá enviar apenas arquivos "*.jpg;*.jpeg;*.gif;*.png"<br />';
}
else
    echo 'Você não enviou nenhum arquivo!';


if (isset($destino1)) {
  $imagem1 = $destino1;
} else {
    $imagem1 = "imagens/sem_imagem.jpg";
}


?>
```

Na teoria, ele deveria pegar a imagem do input file com o name arquivo1 e exibir a imagem... mas ele sempre exibe isso: Você não enviou nenhum arquivo!

Estou usando o WAMP Server, ja aumentei o limit de upload e o limite de post max size nas configurações, e continua não funcionando.. alguém consegue me ajudar??

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Olá.

Isso está ocorrendo porque você não está usando o "enctype form-data".
Quando você faz alguma solicitação através do método POST, você precisa especificar o tipo de codificação que a request irá compor o corpo da sua requisição. Basicamente existem três tipos:

- application/x-www-form-urlencoded (padrão, Todos os caracteres são codificados antes de serem enviados)
- **multipart/form-data** (Nenhum caractere é codificado, necessário para o tráfego de mídias, como é o seu caso)
- text/plain (Espaços são convertidos para símbolos "+", mas nenhuma caractere especial é codificado, evite usar esse formato)

Assim, atributo correto a utilizar é 
`<form enctype="multipart/form-data">`

Boa sorte.

Comment: Show! Agora consegui. Muuuuito obrigado! :)

Answer (score 4):

Troca a abertura do seu form essa tag abaixo e testa novamente:

```
<form class="form-horizontal" method="POST" action="cadastrar_operacional.php" name="form1" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

Comment: Pra deixar a resposta mais clara pra quem perguntou, a diferença da abertura do form está no atributo enctype="multipart/form-data". Esse atributo altera o formato do envio de dados do form e sinaliza o navegador para enviar o arquivo selecionado pelo input para o servidor.

Comment: Vlwww!! Muito obrigado! Eu tinha feito um outro modelo de form que funcionava o upload... mas acho que nesse novo modelo acabei esquecendo do enctype="multipart/form-data". Agora está funcionando novamente! Muuitísssimo obrigado!!